# How to show text in viewport without having to scroll up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

What CSS would allow me to,When scroll down a bit, and click a left element with a big number, showing some text on top of the viewport directly? 
Note that the header area should be filled up. The current code doesn't make "pikachu" fill up the header area.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="header">
<center>
headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea<br>
headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea<br>
headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea<br>
headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea<br>
headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea headerarea<br>
</center>
</div>




<div class="left_container">
<?php
$num=1;
while($num<=200){
    echo "<div class=\"title\">"."click me "."No.".$num."<br>"."</div>";
    $num++;
}
?>
</div>
<div class="right_container">

<!-- <div id="result"></div> -->
</div>

<div class="clear_float">
</div>
</body>

<script>
$(".title").click(function(){
     $(".right_container").css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    $(".right_container").text("pikachu")

})   
</script>

<style>
.left_container{

    position:relative; 
    float:left; width:50%;
}
.right_container{

    position:relative; 
    float:right; width:50%;
}
.title{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to used fixed positioning and top, bottom, left, right to position the element relative to the viewport.

```
.right_container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Edit for your additional requirements.
In your click function, set the positioning to fixed, read the offset, and then set the positioning to absolute with the top set to the offset supplied when the positioning was fixed.

```
$(".title").click(function () {

    var offset = $(".right_container").css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: 0,
        right: 0
    }).offset();

    $(".right_container").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: offset.top,
        right: 0
    });

    $(".right_container").text("pikachu")

})
```

See this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u6muhqbg/1/

Comment: Thanks, but there's another problem I failed to clarified,I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` on the right container. Alternatively, if the content will be taller than the viewport as you mention in your comment, it could be added with `position:relative` and an offset from the top. See below for a complete, working example.

```js
//Add elements via JavaScript instead of PHP for demonstration
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.className = 'title';
  e.innerHTML = 'Click me: ' + i;
  $(e).click(function(){
      $(".right_container")
          .show()
          .text("pikachu")
          .css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
  });
  document.getElementsByClassName('left_container')[0].appendChild(e);
}
```

```css
.left_container{
    position:relative; 
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.right_container{
    position:relative; 
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    height:1000px;
    border:1px dashed red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:none;
}
.title{
    display:block;
    border:1px dashed blue;
    margin:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="left_container"></div>
<div class="right_container"></div>
<div class="clear_float"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's another problem I failed to clarified,I have edited the question.

Comment: @问题大王 In that case, use `position:relative` and set the `top` offset with jQuery. See my updated answer.

Comment: The code works OK on my project code, the right content showed on top of the viewport if not scrolling down, but after I scroll down a bit,after clicking left element, the right content starts to show a bit down relative the view port top, until in the middle of the screen. Can you think of something may cause this? or could you explain the method: .css('top', $(window).scrollTop());  so maybe I can figure the problem out myself.

Comment: @问题大王 That bit of code sets the top position of the element to the window's current scroll position which works in the context of this example. You could try `position:absolute` on the right container instead. Otherwise, that is probably a new issue that should go into a new question.

Comment: Finanlly, found the problem. There was a header area in the page, when scroll down and click left element, the right element didn't fill up the header area, which makes it look like floating in the middle. Do you know how to make "pikachu "fill up the header area thus to be on top of the viewport?  I have modified the code for illustration. Thanks so far!!

Comment: @问题大王 As I said, I believe these new items are out of the scope of your original question, which I believe has been answered. You could absolutely [ask new questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) specifically scoped to your new issues though.